# How fast is the Exploration Speed of a Greater Flying Carpet with two riders?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement, flight

Straight to the references:

[Greater Flying Carpet](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3257) (Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium p85)

> A greater flying carpet carries creatures and objects at a speed of fly 6 and can hover. A character on the carpet can mentally command it to fly as a move action. (...)  If more than one character on the carpet attempts to mentally command it, the carpet responds to each command in turn according to the characters’ initiative order.

[Exploration Speed](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=613)
Nothing specific to quote, just providing a reference to the entry in the compendium for your reading pleasure.

**So what is the exploration speed for the pair of riders (assuming no other companions are present to slow them down)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**60 miles per 10 hour day.**

Working backwards.  A normal speed 6 creature walks 300 feet per minute according to the Exploration Speed chart.

300 feet/minute is 30 feet/round, which is how far a speed 6 creature can move in 1 round.  It appears that they assume that the creature will spend 1 move action per round on movement.

Onto the carpet.

Each character spends 1 move action per round.  Each moves the carpet 6 squares.  However the carpet is one unit and moves both characters each time it moves.  Therefore the total effective speed of the carpet plus two riders is 12.  That results in an overland speed per Day of 60 miles.

Comment: +1. Also, this is a level 20 rare item. It is competing with a ritual of the same level that gives overland flight of 100 miles/day, a level 10 ritual that gives up to an overland flight speed of *30* (quite easily achievable at level 20) and a level 6 ritual that simply offers a base flight speed of 20. It's not even worth thinking about this item to explore with until you can hire a team of pixies to make it "go fast now"

Answer (score 0):

Each rider should be treated as having a fly speed of 6 and therefor would have an exploration speed of 30 miles per day.

Answer (score 0):

The carpet would move 6 squares on each player's turn.  The more player's on it, the faster it could theoretically go.